# Does CallBaseMethod () works for virtual property in FakeItEasy?

Tags: c#, fakeiteasy

I have simple class

```
public class Simple
{
    public virtual int VirtualProperty { get; set; }
}
```

When i run (FakeItEasy.1.13.1)

```
var strict = A.Fake<Simple>(options => options.Strict());
A.CallTo(() => strict.VirtualProperty).CallsBaseMethod();
strict.VirtualProperty = 999;
```

I get an error

```
Call to non configured method "set_VirtualProperty" of strict fake.
```

And I have to

```
var strict = A.Fake<Simple>(options => options.Strict());
A.CallTo(strict).Where(a => a.Method.Name == "get_VirtualProperty").CallsBaseMethod();
A.CallTo(strict).Where(a => a.Method.Name == "set_VirtualProperty").CallsBaseMethod();
strict.VirtualProperty = 999;
```

Does CallBaseMethod () works for virtual property?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suspect that the behavior is a bug, but am on holiday, away from easy access to the code. Consider raiding an issue on github. Or I will when I'm near technology with bigger screens. In the meantime, I think you workaround is the best answer.

Comment: Of course, I meant to suggest raising an issue, not raiding one. We are not Vikings.

Comment: I see you've opened https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/issues/175. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Update: since 2.0.0 has been released, there's a [more convenient way to configure a property setter in some cases](http://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/specifying-a-call-to-configure/#specifying-a-call-to-a-property-setter).**

As more light has been shone on this over at [FakeItEasy Issue 175](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/issues/175), it's become apparent that the real snag is that `A.CallTo(() => strict.VirtualProperty).CallsBaseMethod()` configures the property getter, but not the setter. After that configuration, `get` calls made on `strict.VirtualProperty` will call the base method (property).

However, there's no convenient way to configure the property *setter*. The workaround you have is about as good as it gets.